# python scrapy can not start project

Tags: python, windows, scrapy, anaconda

I use anaconda installed scrapy in windows 10 system. But I can not start the scrapy with `scrapy startproject tutorial`, I got feedback "bash: scrapy: command not found".

After searching in internet, I found a suggestion from a similar topic to add the environment variable: `C:\Users\conny\Anaconda2\Lib\site-packages\scrapy` behind the variable `PATH`, but it still doesn't work.

Do you have any idea, what is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the command `scrapy.bat startproject tutorial`, it should solve the problem.

And you don't need to edit the enviornment path.